# Module not found: can't resolve 'http2' after importing the Clarifai API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, npm-install

I get this error:

```
Failed to compile
./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/server.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'http2' in 'C:\Users\Nene\Desktop\WebWork\face-recognition-app\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Whenever I try to import the Clarifai API, using `create-react-app` to setup.

I'm on a Windows machine running Windows 10
Node version: 16.6.1
npm version: 7.20.3

I'm new to this, any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it got fixed when I install *http2* module,
try using `npm i http2`;